# How To Suppress Shape Border And Background

Tags: openxml, python-pptx

I have python-pptx code that successfully generates shapes containing text.

What I'd like to do is - under program control - suppress the drawing of the shape's border line. Likewise its fill. In some cases I will suppress both - leaving just text within the shape.

How can I achieve this with python-pptx?

I am adept at manipulating the XML so could work with an answer in that style. (Hence tagging with "openxml" as well as "python-pptx".)

Note: Setting the line width to 0 does not have the effect of suppressing the border line - whether visually or logically.

Answer (score 0):

`.background()` does it for both `fill` and `line`.